# Forge viewer memory too big

Tags: autodesk-forge

Currently we are using viewer on mobile devices but after playing around for a while, app crashed.

Webview is used to load models. Is it because of memory leak? When we load some big examples of threejs, crash never happens.
The version of forge viewer is 6.1.

Comment: Could you some relevant code please? That would make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest Viewer v7 for improved memory management and disposal of Three.js objects - see migration guide [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/migration_guide_v6_to_v7/).

There was an issue with memory management and disposal of those objects with earlier versions. As of v7 use `viewer.shutdown` when necessary to unload/reload model for

And there's a memory inspection extension that comes out of the box to help you diagnose memory issues:

```
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MemoryManager')
```

[image]

I will update this answer if you can share more about the issues you are having.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try, now we are upgrading to 6.6, will up to 7 next month. But anyway we will try first in our lab env and share more info.

Comment: Was `viewer.shutdown` deprecated? It's no longer a function on Viewer3D/GuiViewer3D.

Comment: It should be `Autodesk.Viewing.shutdown()` so try `viewer.finish(); Autodesk.Viewing.shutdown()`

Comment: Check heap memory allocation with "window.performance.memory"